# Building a facebook messenger style new message friend addition - uitextfield / uitextview

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to make a fb messenger style new message formation uitextview.. as shown in the image..

[image: fb-image]

Specifically, how to make the uitextview which is at the top of the tableview (showing list of selected friends). I want to make a uitextview with the following properties..

1) It expands/contracts as more names are added/removed to/from it.

2) The textview is editable - but not partially editable, i.e., a name is either wiped out by backspace or not (like how it happens in fb)

3) Possibly this editing happens in nice aesthetics (similar to fb, make the color of the entire text blue colored before backspacing it out)

Comment: 1) textView.height = textView.contentSize.height, I dont understand what your asking in the other two... I don't use the app.

Comment: If you backspace (erase) a name in the app, it erases the complete name at once, for example if the name is 'Mike Gamson', the textfield doesn't allow you to erase it to 'Mike Gams', either erase it completely on backspace.

Comment: objective-c or swift?

Comment: objective-c preferred, does swift make it extremely easy? I am okay switching to swift too..

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I have used objective-c, but I believe this is correct.  It may not be though.  And yes I would eventually switch to swift.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

//you should have an array of names as a property, not here.
NSMutableArray* nameArray = [@"sam"];
if ([text  isEqual: @""]) {// this is delete

    for (NSString *name in nameArray) {
        NSRange nameRange = [textView.text rangeOfString:name];

        if (nameRange.location == range.location) {
            textView.text = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:nameRange withString:@""];
           [nameArray removeObject:name]
           return false;
        }

    }




}

return true;
```

}